# Stored Procedure check from a doctor's schedule if there is an technician for him

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that given a certain time of entry, check if for a certain dentist, if there is an technician with a compatible time to help him.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE(
  schedule_code int,
  start_time TIME,
  end_time TIME,      
  description varchar(80),
  PRIMARY KEY(schedule_code),
  UNIQUE(start_time, end_time));

CREATE TABLE DENTIST_HAS_A_SCHEDULE(
  ssn_dentist int,
  schedule_code int,
  PRIMARY KEY(ssn_dentist, schedule_code),
  FOREIGN KEY(ssn_dentist) references PERSON (ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY(schedule_code) references SCHEDULE(schedule_code));

CREATE TABLE TECHNICIAN_HAS_A_SCHEDULE(
  ssn_technician int,
  schedule_code int,
  PRIMARY KEY(ssn_technician, schedule_code),
  FOREIGN KEY(ssn_technician) references PERSON (ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY(schedule_code) references SCHEDULE(schedule_code));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `DentisthasSchedule`(technicianSchedule TIME)
BEGIN
    declare timeTechnician TIME;
    set timeTechnician = (SELECT from );
    
END$$
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding, you're saying that given a TIME, you want to return the first dentist that is not already linked to the schedule for that time and also first technician that is not already linked to the schedule for that time? And how do you want the output to be formatted?

Comment: Excuse. I ended up not making it clear what I'm looking for. I want to inform a TIME about a dentist and from there check if there is a technician available for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select where something is not linked, one option is to use a subquery.  Something like this

```
select ssn_technician from PERSON where ssn_technician is not null and ssn_technician not in 
   (select ssn_technician from TECHNICIAN_HAS_A_SCHEDULE ts inner join SCHEDULE s on ts.schedule_code = s.schedule_code 
    where s.start_time = [time that you want to check] )
```

So what you're doing is selecting all the technicians that are assigned to that time, then selecting the Person whose SSN is not in that list.

Comment: I got confused. I want to check if there is a technician available from the time given by the dentist. The technician will assist the dentist and for this they need to have the same time.

Comment: But in that case if there are other employees besides the dentist, they will be selected, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I overlooked that. My example has been edited to specifically check that there is something in the ssn_technician field. Assuming that only technicians have that field filled out.